# Is it possible to create a column with height equal to its width in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

Is it possible to create a column with height equal to its width in Bootstrap 4?

The first 2 columns should be quadratic and third one has height as previous columns. Is it possible?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is unfortunatly not available yet in bootstrap 4.
but yet you can do what you want with `display: grid`.

here's a full guide on grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but not with CSS & Bootstrap. There is a workaround and you can use `<svg>` to maintain the ratio of your columns.

You need to place an empty `<svg>` inside a column to maintain the ratio. Use it with bootstrap class `invisible` to make sure it's never visible. Place your content using `position:absolute`.

For 3:2 ratio set `viewBox="0 0 3 2"` and so on.

However there is a catch. If you have a layout with different column size like `col-3` and `col-6` you need to adjust `viewBox=""` for each size. For example for `col-3` use `viewBox="0 0 1 1"` and for `col-6` must use `viewBox="0 0 2 1"` to maintain `col-3` ratio. Remember - in bootstrap columns are stretched to the same size.

Check out my demo.

```css
/*DEMO*/body{padding:3rem}

.content{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row border">
  <div class="col-3 border border-primary">
    <svg class="invisible" viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg>
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 border border-danger">
    <svg class="invisible" viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg>
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 border border-success">
    <svg class="invisible" viewBox="0 0 2 1"></svg>
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
```